# Macro finds change in column L - how do copy rows below

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I've written the following code to identify a change in column L and to copy that row.

How do I alter the code so that it copies that row and the 20 rows below below it?

```
Sub CopyRowsAtChangeInValue()
Dim lRow As Long

  For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow, "L") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "L") Then
        Rows(CStr(lRow) & ":" & CStr(lRow)).Select
        Selection.Copy
    End If
  Next lRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add 20 rows to the last row number.

```
Sub CopyRowsAtChangeInValue()
Dim lRow As Long

  For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow, "L") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "L") Then
        Rows(CStr(lRow) & ":" & CStr(lRow + 20)).Select
        Selection.Copy
    End If
  Next lRow

End Sub
```

You can also minimize the code, by copying the rows without selecting.

```
Rows(CStr(lRow) & ":" & CStr(lRow + 20)).Copy
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like that...

```
Sub CopyRowsAtChangeInValue()
Dim lRow As Long

  For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow, "L") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "L") Then
        Rows(lRow & ":" & lRow + 20).Copy
    End If
  Next lRow

End Sub
```